# Spring Data MongoDB - how to set maxTimeMS for Aggregation pipeline query

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I've noticed that org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOption class covers just a small subset of these options described within MongoDB Aggregation pipeline documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#syntax

I need to set maxTimeMS option, but it is not available within org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOption:

```
public class AggregationOptions {
private static final String BATCH_SIZE = "batchSize";
private static final String CURSOR = "cursor";
private static final String EXPLAIN = "explain";
private static final String ALLOW_DISK_USE = "allowDiskUse";
private static final String COLLATION = "collation";
private static final String COMMENT = "comment";
...
```

However, the another class (of mongodb-driver) actually has such field maxTimeMS,
com.mongodb.AggregationOptions:

```
public class AggregationOptions {
private final Integer batchSize;
private final Boolean allowDiskUse;
private final OutputMode outputMode;
private final long maxTimeMS;
private final Boolean bypassDocumentValidation;
private final Collation collation;
...
```

Any idea/tricks how to set this maxTimeMS for Aggregation query using Spring Data MongoDB API? Or maybe do I need to build/write such aggregation by using native query?

Btw. I know that Spring Data MongoDB supports maxTimeMS for find operations, for example:

```
Query.query(mongoCriteria).with(pageable).maxTime(Duration.ofMinutes(4))
```

However I need to set aggregation query processing timeout on server side in order to prevent "never ending" queries that kill performance.

spring-data-mongodb:2.2.0.RELEASE

Comment: I think there is no other way than using native query

Comment: I opened [DATAMONGO-2390](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2390) to add support for `maxTimeMS` to `AggregationOptions`.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to set a time limit to my query and it took me some time to find the answer; so, I want to share my method with anyone who might be interested:

```
AggregationOptions aggregationOptions = new AggregationOptions.Builder().maxTime(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).build();
Aggregation aggregate = Aggregation.newAggregation(match).withOptions(aggregationOptions);
```